# Insert value into input field using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm using the line of code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"sernum\"]")).sendKeys("XXXXXXXXXX");
```

All I need to do is insert a value in the field. But it isn't work...

The fragment from "dom":

[image]

Comment: [EDIT] your question and post error stack as well your relevant HTML?

Answer (score 0):

To send a character sequence within the `<input>` field as the element is a dynamic element you need to use [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#sernum[name=\"sernum\"]"))).sendKeys("XXXXXXXXXX");
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='sernum' and @name=\"sernum\"]"))).sendKeys("XXXXXXXXXX");
  ```